# Does AWS EC2 blocks torrent sites like torrentz.eu?

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, amazon-web-services, torrent

Initially when trying `ping torrentz.eu`, dns was not resolving the `torrentz.eu` domain name on my AWS EC2 micro instance(Ubuntu), Then I have added google public dns to the `resolv.conf`. So my instance started resolving the `torrentz.eu` domain name to their IP. But when I use [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to check the access to `torrentz.eu`,  `wget torrentz.eu` shows the following

```
--2015-05-30 19:11:07--  http://torrentz.eu/
Resolving torrentz.eu (torrentz.eu)... 185.87.147.4, 185.87.147.3
Connecting to torrentz.eu (torrentz.eu)|185.87.147.4|:80...
```

For any other sites `wget` immediately loads the `index.html`. I have tried loading `torrentz.eu` in [elinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks) also it is showing `connecting..` message for long time. Does access to torrent sites like `torrentz.eu` blocked in AWS EC2 Instance ?  How do we get know who is blocking `aws` or `torrentz.eu` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to AWS support. Incidentally, how do you know this isn't a block on `torrentz.eu`'s end to prevent scrapers / DDOS attacks?

Comment: actually that is my question, Is this from `torrentz.eu` or `aws` , who is blocking?

Comment: Ask them. How would we know?

Comment: I thought anyone who faced  similar situation in `aws` or `torrent` could help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect it's torrentz.eu doing the blocking.

If I run traceroute on 185.87.147.3 from EC2 I get:

```
traceroute to 185.87.147.3 (185.87.147.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  216.182.224.228 (216.182.224.228)  1.424 ms 216.182.224.200 (216.182.224.200)  1.168 ms 216.182.224.228 (216.182.224.228)  1.403 ms
 2  100.64.14.17 (100.64.14.17)  0.812 ms 100.64.2.75 (100.64.2.75)  1.281 ms 100.64.8.215 (100.64.8.215)  0.937 ms
 3  100.64.0.120 (100.64.0.120)  1.194 ms 100.64.0.210 (100.64.0.210)  1.003 ms 100.64.0.112 (100.64.0.112)  1.177 ms
 4  100.64.16.69 (100.64.16.69)  0.328 ms 100.64.16.29 (100.64.16.29)  0.810 ms 100.64.16.55 (100.64.16.55)  0.270 ms
 5  205.251.245.241 (205.251.245.241)  1.217 ms  1.226 ms 205.251.245.235 (205.251.245.235)  1.236 ms
 6  72.21.220.46 (72.21.220.46)  1.180 ms 72.21.220.30 (72.21.220.30)  5.956 ms  5.896 ms
 7  xe-7-1-2.was14.ip4.gtt.net (77.67.68.153)  1.318 ms xe-7-2-0.was10.ip4.gtt.net (216.221.156.185)  1.311 ms xe-11-0-0.was14.ip4.gtt.net (173.241.128.45)  1.346 ms
 8  xe-2-1-0.mtl30.ip4.gtt.net (89.149.186.210)  13.941 ms  13.947 ms  13.930 ms
 9  as10929.xe-1-1-0.cr1.mtl1.ca.as4436.gtt.net (69.31.142.122)  16.335 ms  16.296 ms  16.282 ms
10  xe-0-0-3-3904.CR3.1250RL.as10929.net (209.44.125.216)  13.941 ms  13.944 ms  13.939 ms
11  xe-0-0-0.CR1.800SQ.as10929.net (199.193.53.27)  18.318 ms  18.294 ms  18.318 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

And if I run that from my local machine I stop getting replies at step 11 too.

However if I inspect the traffic from EC2 via wireshark I get:
[image: wireshark]

ie. I'm not getting any acknowledgement to my SYN packets.

I don't think AWS would have a strong incentive to block these sites seeing as bandwidth is pretty expensive, but these sites would definitely have an incentive to block scrapers being run by AWS customers.

Comment: Ah the magic of traceroute.